# What's causing this boot freeze?

Tags: boot, freeze, windows-server-2012, toshiba-laptop

My [Toshiba Satellite Pro A300-28R](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/satellite-pro-a300-28r/?service=UK&com.broadvision.session.new=Yes&PRODUCT_ID=1067894) runs Windows Server 2012 set up as a [workstation](http://www.win2012workstation.com/).

The setup has been stable for over a year, but now it sometimes freezes when booting from a cold state.

The laptop is about five years old, so I suspect a failure of some hardware component.

## Boot Freeze

Sometimes the screen, fan, and lights fail for a second before the machine tries again. Sometimes the boot freezes and I have to force a power cycle.

If the system reaches the login screen, everything is okay until I turn off.

The Windows startup freeze looks like this:

[image: laptop freezes on boot]

[See it flicker on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/79289194)

The spinner stops, the Windows logo is smeared across the screen, and vertical blue lines flicker across the bottom of the screen. I've taken to calling it the 'streaky window of death'.

## Event Log suggests power failure

Recent event log content points toward some sort of power failure.

I filtered the system event log for critical and error events in the last 30 days.

**[Inspect the filtered log](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5017cd4b43b78efe7ec588de/5282f19412b45ec711008551/162c437eed4baca60b4a1008fbb5252f/system_errors_and_criticals.xml)**

There are eight recent Kernel-Power events.

The oldest Kernel-Power event (ID 137) calls out the firmware:

> The system firmware has changed the processer's memory type range registers (MTRRs) across a sleep state transition (S4). This can result in reduced resume performance.

The other Kernel-Power events (ID 41) warn about improper shutdowns:

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

An EventLog event (ID 6008) follows seconds later, also blaming the shutdown:

> The previous system shutdown at 03:01:34 on 06/11/2013 was unexpected.

## What unexpected shutdown?

The shutdown times are accurate, but they should not be unexepected.

To shut down my laptop, I run a script on my desktop called 'Shut Down.bat'. It contains this command:

```
shutdown /p
```

The shutdown process always appears to complete normally. The subsequent boot is where the pain starts.

How could I test the power failure theory?

Should I analyze the shutdown history more throughly? How?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  We can only guess what your cause is, especially with the lack of information provided.  There are lots of guides on the Internet, and similar/related questions here on SU, all about basic troubleshooting.   To give you a push: Clean the vents out, run RAM tests, run disk tests, look at logs (may have to boot form a 3rd party disk), etc.  Then, if you're still stuck, come back with specific questions about specific problems.

Comment: @techie007 Added my event log analysis. It's the best lead I have. I also performed a memory test, a hard disk test, and an optical boot test. If you think the results would help, I'll add them as well.